# AWS EC2 Instance Status Check says "Instance reachability check failed"

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2

AWS EC2 status check displays: "Instance reachability check failed". On checking the system log no error is seen. The log file ends with the login prompt. Checked the screenshot of the system also, which too shows the login prompt. SSH is enabled in the inbound rules. The instance has been working fine for a long time now. Today I tried stoppting/starting and rebooting the instance. The instance is running ubuntu 18.04. The website associated with the server is down too. Around 67% of 29GB storage is used. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**
[image: The CPU Credit Balance]
Is the graph behaviour related to this issue?

Comment: Have you followed AWS instructions? Have you considered restoring from a snapshot? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/system-reachability-check/

Comment: I couldn't find a related case there

Comment: Best restore from backup then.